# return instance of the creation of a record in a pivot table

Tags: laravel

I have a pivot table to create a follower system.

I need that when I create the record of a new follower I get back the instance of that record.

**MODEL USER**

```
 public function followers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'leader_id', 'follower_id');
    }
```

I create the record like this:

```
$this->user->followers()->attach(auth()->user()->id);
```

But if I try to return the instance like this, it returns nothing.

```
$follow = $this->user->followers()->attach(auth()->user()->id);
```

How else can I do it?

Comment: could you post your relationships models

Comment: I have added the relationship

Comment: Did you try this `$follow = $this->user->followers()->attach(auth()->user()->id)->get();`

Comment: Call to a member function get() on null

Comment: can you post your contoller code

Comment: it must be like this  ```public function followUser(int $profileId)
{
  $user = User::find($profileId);  $user->followers()->attach(auth()->user()->id);}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach function doesn't return anything. If you want get your pivot try:

```
      $userFollowerPivot = $this
            ->user
            ->followers()
            ->where('followers.id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->first()
            ->pivot;
```